# Exporting mysql data to csv file in the home directory ubuntu

Tags: java, mysql, excel, csv, ubuntu

I have a table in mysql and now I am trying to export the entire data into a csv file. As per the documentation, a possible way of doing this is with the query:

```
SELECT id, name, email INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users WHERE 1
```

This works perfectly fine, but it creates the file in my `tmp` directory of the filesystem. I want the file to be in the project directory in my eclipse workspace (I am using java).

So, next, what I tried was copying this file to my destination (using apache commons io) and then deleting the file. But I am not able to delete the file ("java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file:", I am assuming this is because I don't have root access to tmp directory).

Is there any other elegant method of doing what I want...or do I have to use a library like apache POI?

Comment: try running the program as sudo, or change your outfile path

Comment: @gtgaxiola changing the outfilepath doesn't work, as 'INTO OUTFILE' only creates file  where my mysql server is hosted. Anyway, I am looking for a more elegant solution (sorry, but I don't want to use sudo)

Comment: Do you have admin access to the mysql Server? Can you create a directory with appropriate chmod permissions for your Program? Then you may change the outfile path

Comment: @gtgaxiola I have a separate username and password for my mysql server, and I can create a directory in chmod, from the terminal if I am signed in as root, if thats what you mean to ask

Comment: In your Mysql Server if there is a way you can create a directory where to put your csv files that has a more lenient chmod permissions (like allowing delete from specific users/gropus) then you can change your MySQL script to point to that directory instead of /tmp/

Answer (score 1):

The solution from the following [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/how-to-use-a-different-tmp-dir-for-into-outfile-select-with-mysql) worked for me.

Use Command-line>mysql -e "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY bar" > '/path/to/file'